# Change FROM email address on emailed forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I need to be able to change the "from" email address when the form info gets emailed to me. The form captures the customers' email addresses...and when the email of all that info gets to us its currently showing from "no-reply@cognitoforms.com" and I need the from email to be the customer's email address he/she entered on that form. How can I get it to change this?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for Cognito Forms. We cannot change who the email is coming from. The from address will always be “no-reply@cognitoforms.com” however if you have a name field inside of your form you should be seeing the users name as part of the subject line.

In later releases we do plan to give you the ability to change what the subject line of the notification email looks like. You can follow the progress of this on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/GPZadDc0).

Comment: I will add to this that we are considering ways to set the Reply-To address to be the email address of the individual who submitted the form.  This would effectively solve your problem because the Reply-To appears in your email client in most cases, and all replies would go back to the correct individual.